# Search for a number from a list in a line, Print that line

Tags: python

```
import heapq

def main():
        with open("highscores.txt", "r+")as file:
        file.seek(0)
        scores = file.readlines()

    scorelist = []
    for line in scores:
        raw = line.split()
        score = float(raw[1])
        scorelist.append(score)
    print(scorelist)
    topfive = heapq.nsmallest(5,scorelist)
    print(topfive)
    for i in scorelist:
        for line in scores:
            if scorelist[i] in line:
                print(line)
main()
```

Hello,

I'm trying to search each line in a text file for each number in the list topfive. If that number is in the line, then the line should be printed. I keep getting the error: List indices must be integers or slices, not float. Can anybody help me, sorry I'm new to programming.

This is the contents of the txt file:

```
alex .34
donny .41
jeezy .31
lonny .11
gonny .31
monty .53
pip .65
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are going for. If you are getting the correct scores when you

```
print(scorelist)
```

then you should see that not all of the scores are integers i.e. some have decimal points. Lets say

```
scorelist = [1, 2, 3.5]
```

when you iterate through the scorelist

```
for i in scorelist:
    print i
```

you should get

```
1

2

3.5
```

then when you call

```
scorelist[i]
```

the 3.5 is causing the error. Hopefully this helps

Edit: This may help you. Iterating through a list in python will return an element of the list each iteration. You are not getting an index with i. In fact you don't even need indexing

```
for score in scorelist:
    for line in scores:
        if score in line:
            print(line)
```